# Local WebSite: run default browser

Tags: html, browser, web, local, cd

I need to create a brochure-cd from a website I did. All resources are html, images and xml, so i don't have any problem at all in accessing file system. My question is: once I open my index.html page in browser, how can I set the params of the window (eg: show addressbar, show statusbar, etc)

Thanks

(If you have an alternative idea of how run an html based brochure on CD just let me know)

EDIT: Specs changed, I've just knewn I must write xml and upload file, too. Any idea? I'm considering Adobe Air, but would be amazing if I can compile a whole .NET website into an exe..... Anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can set these is when you open the page, not after it's already present. So, you will probably have to have a start page, which then opens your new page, with the parameters you want.

Be warned though, if you have any JavaScript, many browsers won't allow scripts to run locally, or will present a nasty warning message before it will execute.

You may look into having a small desktop application on the CD that launches an instance of a browser inside of itself, assuming you can run the browser on every machine this will be run on. This will probably give you the look you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. You can only set params of a window you create. So you'll have to run a script on load that creates a new window and then closes the initial window.

There is however no way that this script is executed without warnings, if at all.

An alternative would be to develop an executable that is able to display the page, but that might not be easy, especially when you want to be browser and platform independent.